# How to use mysql query to select only rows where column value contains value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query as below. Bit new to all this. I am selecting rows that contain specific words in one column - location column has values like 'Spain>Canary Islands>Lanzarote>Playa Lanzarote'.

I can find rows that contain a specific value but I need to refine it so it only matches rows where the 3rd value after each '>' is the same, rather than the whole value.

```
$location = 'Lanzarote';

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT *    
FROM $tablename 
WHERE location LIKE '%%$location%%'
ORDER BY rating
LIMIT 10
"));
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I have spent hours searching and trying various things. I thought SUBSTRING_INDEX might work but no luck as this seems to apply to the result set.

Comment: Are there always four parts to the location, or could that number vary?

Comment: How does your query with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` look like?

Comment: yes there are always 4 parts

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *    
FROM $tablename 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, '>', 4), '>', -1) LIKE '%$location%'
ORDER BY rating
LIMIT 10
```

If there is less than 4 parts in a path (less than 3 `'>'` symbols) then the last part will be tested.

Comment: there are always four parts tks so much will give it a whirl